# i need a query too see the result after executing a cursor

Tags: plsql

I executed the below cursor in pl sql and it was successsful. I want to see the result set of this cursor. Can someone help me?

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR UserId_in_11_cur
   IS
      SELECT userid
        FROM VW_usrapi_user_group
       WHERE GroupId = 11;
BEGIN
   FOR  VW_usrapi_user_group
   IN UserId_in_11_cur
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         VW_usrapi_user_group.UserId);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set serverout on size 100000
DECLARE
   CURSOR UserId_in_11_cur
   IS
      SELECT userid
        FROM VW_usrapi_user_group
       WHERE GroupId = 11;
BEGIN
   dbms_output.enable(100000);
   FOR  VW_usrapi_user_group
   IN UserId_in_11_cur
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         VW_usrapi_user_group.UserId);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

You have to make additional settings and calls DBMS_OUTPUT.enable.

Comment: Hi 
Im getting invalid option error for the 1st line and UserId_in_11_cur need to be declared error within the begin and end loop

Comment: where are u executing this?sql developer or sqlplus?

Comment: Hi,If i use the below script will it work?..i mean will it pass p_userID to the procedure one by one or else it will pass all the p_userID atonce..becoz the select statement inside cursor returns 3 values.if it doesnot pass the values one by one can you pls help me in modifying this cursor.

DECLARE
   CURSOR UserId_in_11_cur
   IS
      SELECT userid into p_userID
       FROM VW_usrapi_user_group
      WHERE GroupId = 11;
BEGIN
   FOR  VW_usrapi_user_group
   IN UserId_in_11_cur
   LOOP
   mosaic.PCK_RSTAPI_RESTRICTIONS.AddRestrictionEditor(p_restrictionID, p_userID,1);     
   END LOOP;
END;

Comment: It works in sqlplus, not developer.  If you can run developer, you very likely  have the oracle client installed on your desktop.  That means you can also run sqlplus.

Comment: this compiles successfully in plsql developer... but im not sure whether the
 LOOP mosaic.PCK_RSTAPI_RESTRICTIONS.AddRestrictionEditor(p_restrictionID, p_userID,1); END LOOP;

is capable of handling multiple values...

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line can take values from different datatypes. PL/SQL knows the datatype of  the cursor object.  It won't work as is. DBMS_OUTPUT is not interactive, it dumps everything to the terminal when the module ends.  Not during the run.

Comment: instead of DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line im calling a procedure by passing 3 values to p_userID, will the procedure handle this by taking one value ata time??

mosaic.PCK_RSTAPI_RESTRICTIONS.AddRestrictionEditor(p_restrictionID, p_userID,1); 

will this handle multiple values